# Add Reversed Numbers

Tags: c++, numbers

Given 2 numbers A and B, reverse the 2 numbers, add them and print the sum.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

unsigned reverse(unsigned num){
  unsigned reversed = 0;
  while(num){
    reversed = reversed*10+num%10;
    num = num/10;
  }
  return reversed;
}

int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n--){
        unsigned num1,num2;
        scanf("%u %u",&num1,&num2);
        printf("%u\n",reverse(reverse(num1)+reverse(num2)));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output:

113
3231
624

Expected Output

311
1323
426

solution please....................

Comment: Or Java? Please keep your question tags language/problem specific.

Comment: It doesn't say to reverse the sum, perhaps you can just remove that.

Comment: BTW `001` backwards is `100`

Comment: Looks like you already have a solution. Is there anything about it which you do not like and want to discuss?

Answer (score 1):

Problem is here.

```
printf("%u\n",reverse(reverse(num1)+reverse(num2)));
```

it should be

```
printf("%u\n",reverse(num1)+reverse(num2))
```

You are again calling `reverse` on `sum` of reversed numbers.